# Calculating credible region for odds ratio

Tags: probability, bayesian, confidence-interval, change-of-variable

I have a problem where I need to calculate the credible region for the odds ratio $\frac{\theta}{1-\theta}$. This is part of a bigger problem where I have already calculated 90% credible region for random variable $\theta$:

> $$P(\theta\leq 0.30)=0.05$$ $$P(\theta\leq 0.52)=0.95$$
>   $$P(0.30\leq \theta\leq 0.52)=0.9.$$

Now I need to calculate the 90% credible region for $\frac{\theta}{1-\theta}.$ This is what I tried: first,

$$P\left(\frac{\theta}{1-\theta}\leq a\right)=P\left(\theta\leq \frac{1}{1+a}\right),$$

so now I took advantage of my earlier results: in order for

$$P\left(\frac{\theta}{1-\theta}\leq a\right)=P\left(\theta\leq \frac{1}{1+a}\right)=0.05,$$

I must have $\frac{1}{1+a}=0.30$ or $a=2.39$. Similarly, for the case

$$P\left(\frac{\theta}{1-\theta}\leq b\right)=P\left(\theta\leq \frac{1}{1+b}\right)=0.95,$$

I must have $\frac{1}{1+b}=0.52$ or $b=0.93$. So now I have:

$P\left(\frac{\theta}{1-\theta}\leq 2.39\right)=0.05$ and $P\left(\frac{\theta}{1-\theta}\leq 0.93\right)=0.95$. And now by looking at the numbers something seems to be wrong.

**Question: Do you think I should suspect my earlier results for $\theta$ or did I do something illegal in my reasoning here?**

Update: The distribution for $\theta$ is $Beta(21,31)$.

Comment: Not an answer, but a plea. Please don't report all those spurious decimal places. Since the right hand sides of your expressions use just two that's the most we should see on the left.

Comment: @EthanBolker I rounded the numbers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be careful in that your manipulation only works if $\theta \le 1$. You say that $\theta$ comes from a beta distribution though, so you're good.

You have a small algebra mistake: it should be

$$P\left(\frac\theta{1-\theta} \le a\right)=P\left(\theta \le \frac a{1+a}\right) = 0.05$$ which implies

$a=0.42$ and similarly

$$P\left(\frac\theta{1-\theta} \le b\right)=P\left(\theta \le \frac b{1+b}\right) = 0.95$$ which implies

$b=1.08$

Comment: Perfect! thank you very much, it's always something very obvious what you don't see x) I wasn't being careful enough.

Comment: Hi @Ant I got curious and don't immediately see why we must have $\theta \leq 1$? Could you refreshen my memory please :) thank you!

Comment: @jjepsuomi When you multiply both sides by $1-\theta$ you don't reverse the inequality, which is correct only when $1-\theta \ge 0 \implies \theta \le 1$

Comment: Aah, I see yes indeed. Thanks for that, your super ;)